# Separating chocolate-coated cookies stuck together

Tags: chocolate, cookies

I purchased some really nice chocolate-covered cookies that were packaged in a metal tin.  The cookies must have been stored somewhere warm, because the individual cookies are stuck together.  How can I separate them without ruining them?

Comment: Try freezing them.

Answer (score 1):

Short of re-melting/reheating them you can't do this without some mechanical separation such as cutting between each cookie. You may find that you can do this most easily with a heated knife - dip it in hot/boiling water for a few seconds to heat the blade.